# Azure Log Analytics Getting IOPs

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-log-analytics

I'm trying to find the Avg. Disk sec/Write and Avg. Disk sec/Read on disks in azure using log analytics, but I keep getting errors. I'm reluctantly trying OMS as I haven't found a way to get the information through Powershell.

Is there a way on Powershell to get IOPS, without querying PerfMon counters? I'd like to query the disks directly through the portal, which does show the information. I'll add the powershell tag in case anyone can shed some light on this.

I tried these on log analytics

```
Perf 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(7d) 
| where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "Avg. Disk sec/Write" 
| summarize (TimeGenerated, Avg_Disk_Write)=arg_max(TimeGenerated, CounterValue) by Computer, InstanceName 
| where strlen(InstanceName) ==2 and InstanceName contains ":";
let Avg_Disk_Write=
Perf 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(7d) 
| where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "Avg. Disk sec/Read" 
| summarize (TimeGenerated, Avg_Disk_Read)=arg_max(TimeGenerated, CounterValue) by Computer, InstanceName 
| where strlen(InstanceName) ==2 and InstanceName contains ":";
Avg_Disk_Read
| join (
   disk_free_MB 
) on Computer, InstanceName
| project Computer, InstanceName, Avg_Disk_Write, Avg_Disk_Read
```

Which didn't help I then tried

```
Perf 
| where ObjectName == "Capacity and Performance" and (CounterName == "VHD Reads/s" or CounterName == "VHD Writes/s") 
| summarize AggregatedValue = avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 7d), CounterName, InstanceName
```

None of which have helped, I was hoping you could point me in the right direction...
 
I'm trying to understand the IOPS for disks to consider whether a resize operation may be viable.

Thanks in advance :)